# Traverse transitive keys in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, traversal

I have `Map<String, String>` which contains elements like: {“a”=”b”, “b”=”c”, “c”=”d”, “z”=”y”, …}.

I need a method:

```
List<String> getTransitiveKeys(String startKey);// assuming the map is visible somehow as `map`
```

When `getTransitiveKeys(“a”)` is called, it will return [“a”, “b”, “c”]. When `getTransitiveKeys (“z”)` is called, it will return [“z”].

Recursion needed in the method?

Thanks!

Comment: Just looks like a homework. I just abstract the problem and want a neat way to implement the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> getTransitiveKey(String key) {
   List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
   while(map.containsKey(key)) {
    // avoid endless loops
    if(result.contains(key)) {
      break;
    }

    result.add(key);  
    key = map.get(key)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why recursion ? just a single loop

```
while(map.get(startKey) != null) {
    startKey =  map.get(startKey);
}
```